# Group by to Avoid with Aggregate function

Tags: sql-server

I have query where I am using Case when statement to  get no of customer covered on particular date
, but in that I have some filter to apply , I want only those customer covered where Invoice Number is not zero .
But When I am putting Invoice no in case then asking me to do group by and group by is giving me result invoice by invoice, I need a single query result, If I don't write  InvoiceNo!='0' then I am getting single line result but I want to put this Filter, I tried while putting Sum also before case but gives me an error that *Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery*

this is my query

```
select sum(Amt) as Amnt, LineManager, Staffname ,   month(date) as month , FORMAT(date, 'dddd') AS [Day Name]
,**(CASE     WHEN (Order_type ='SALES_ORDER' and InvoiceNo!='0'   ) THEN COUNT(DISTINCT(customer)) else 0    END) as  [Customercovered]**

from SalesTrasncation Salest        
INNER JOIN Customer cus ON Salest.SITE=cus.customercode     
WHERE date between  '2022-11-24' and '2022-11-24'       
group by    LineManager,Staffname , month(date) ,date,order_type ;
```

Comment: Can you please add sample data and expected output?  It would be the best if you can provide DDL command

Comment: It's difficult to understand what's your requirements.

Comment: You use SUM() which is aggregate function. Aggregate functions are often used with the GROUP BY. Please read doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I think the issue is GROUP BY cries that you're not grouping on the items used within the CASE statement. But if you then put them in it no longer groups how you want (I'm assuming in this case the InvoiceNo is possibly your primary key so you end up with each row individually and no aggregation )